# Regex - matching world which contain only vowels or consonants

Tags: regex

I have problem with regex. I want to match only these words which contains only vowel or consonants.

For example I have strings like this:

```
aeyiuo 
aeYYuo 
qrcbk 
aeeeee 
normal 
Text 
extTT
```

My regex should match: `aeyiuo aeYYuo aeeeee`

I don't know why my expression doesn't work `^[aeyiuo]*|[^aeyiuo]*$`
To check my regexp I use online parsers: http://www.regexr.com/ or http://regexpal.com/

If somebody could explain me my mistake, I would be very grateful.

Comment: ``^`` matches the start of the whole string, not of a word. Similarly, ``$`` matches the end of the string, not the end of a word. How you can reliably match the end of a word depends a bit on which regex engine you are using. Please say which programming language you want to use this with.

Comment: what sort of output you want from the above string??

Comment: Yes, please specify what language you are using.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you want to match lines with only vowels then you just need to think about a character class `[]`.
What should we add to it ? Vowels ! `[aeiouy]`.
We need it one or more times, so let's add a plus sign to it `[aeiouy]+`.
We also need to anchor it `^[aeiouy]+$`.
Now let's talk about the modifiers, we need the `i` modifier to match case insensitive. We also need the `m` modifier so that `^` and `$` will match begin of line and end of line respectively. Also don't forget the `g` modifier, in some engines you need it to match all occurences.

<kbd>[**Online demo**](http://regex101.com/r/sW3mX8)</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

To simplify things why not check against two different expressions?

`^[aeyiuo]+$` for only vowels

`^[^aeyiuo]+$` for only consonants.

Unless your requirement is to use only one regex. Check for case sensitivity or insensitivity too.

Comment: I must do it in one expression :( unfortunately your solution with + symbol doesn't work.

Comment: This is wrong, see my comment on the question about ``^`` and ``$``.

Comment: plus means one or more occurrence of the pattern. star means it may be zero occurrence. so a[ ]*b means a and b separated by zero or more spaces. if you put plus it means atleast one space should be there for match. If you use star, your empty string will also match but it contains no vowels !

Comment: @ChristianAichinger Saw your comment. I assumed each string will have regex applied and will have separate regexes to check for vowel only and consonant only. The accepted answer assumes the same. I find it easier to have simpler and smaller regular expressions, and use code for splitting the string and performing OR operations in code rather than in regex.

Comment: Note that `^[^aeyiuo]+$` will also match `12345`.  Probably best to NOT use negative character class in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want only vowels `aeiyou` try: `\b[aeiyou]+\b`.

Only consonants (or any other non-vowel char) would be: `\b[^\b\saeiyou]+\b`

So you get: `\b[aeiyou]+\b|\b[^\b\saeiyou]+\b`

which matches: `aeyiuo aeYYuo qrcbk aeeeee`

It will match `qrcbk` as well contrary to you example.

I hope I didn't misunderstand...

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow ! I've formatted your answer to make it more readable but next time try to explore and use StackOverflow's formatting tool.

Comment: Also `\b` in a character class `[\b]` will match a backspace (ASCII 8). I don't think you meant that :)

Answer (score 0):

Your regex now checks if it matches `^[aeyiuo]*` or `[^aeyiuo]*$` (notice absence of $ in first expression and absence of ^ in second one).

You have two options:

1. Add parenthesis around both expressions:

   `^([aeyiuo]*|[^aeyiuo]*)$`
2. Add ^ and $ to both expressions

   `^[aeyiuo]*$|^[^aeyiuo]*$`

Answer (score 0):

if([^aeiou])                      //False,then only vowels
if([^b-df-hj-np-tv-z])            //False,then only Consonants

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Take a moment to read through the [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites.

Answer (score 0):

*answer*: `^([^aeiouyAEIOUY0-9\W]+)$|^([aeiouyAEIOUY]+)$`

> **Explained:** starting at the beginning of the string`^`any non(`[^`vowel, number,
>   non-word-character`\W`)`]` *note the double negative* occurring once
>   or more in a row`+` to the end of the string`$` or`|` starting at the
>   beginning of the string`^`any vowel occurring once or more in a row`+`
>   to the end of the string`$`

if that helps any =D

---

#### break it down:

> vowel grouping: `([aeiouyAEIOUY]+)`
>   
>   consonant grouping: `([^aeiouyAEIOUY0-9\W]+)`
>   
>   vowels only string: `^([aeiouyAEIOUY]+)$`
>   
>   consonant only string: `^([^aeiouyAEIOUY0-9\W]+)$`
>
> *same as above only grouped:* 
>   vowels only or consonants only string: `(^([^aeiouyAEIOUY0-9\W]+)$|^([aeiouyAEIOUY]+))$)`

#### Bonus:

> consonant including `y` if followed by vowel: `(y(?=[aeiouAEIOU]))|([^aeiouAEIOU0-9\W])`